# C++ function types

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, std-function

I have a problem understanding function types (they appear e.g. as the `Signature` template parameter of a `std::function`):

```
typedef int Signature(int); // the signature in question

typedef std::function<int(int)>  std_fun_1;
typedef std::function<Signature> std_fun_2;

static_assert(std::is_same<std_fun_1, std_fun_2>::value,
              "They are the same, cool.");

int square(int x) { return x*x; }

Signature* pf = square;   // pf is a function pointer, easy
Signature f;              // but what the hell is this?
f(42);                    // this compiles but doesn't link
```

The variable `f` can not be assigned, but can be called. Weird. What is it good for, then?

Now if I const-qualify the typedef, I can still use it to build further types but apparently for nothing else:

```
typedef int ConstSig(int) const;

typedef std::function<int(int) const>  std_fun_3;
typedef std::function<ConstSig>        std_fun_4;

static_assert(std::is_same<std_fun_3, std_fun_4>::value,
              "Also the same, ok.");

ConstSig* pfc = square; // "Pointer to function type cannot have const qualifier"
ConstSig fc;            // "Non-member function cannot have const qualifier"
```

What remote corner of the language have I hit here? How is this strange type called and what can I use it for outside of template parameters?

Comment: The standard simply allows you to *declare* functions through a typedef to their signature (actually, function type).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's the relevant paragraph from the Standard. It pretty much speaks for itself.

> 8.3.5/10
>
> A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function (8.4).
>
> *Example:*
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> F  fv;         // OK: equivalent to void fv();
> F  fv { }      // ill-formed
> void fv() { }  // OK: definition of fv
> ```
>
> A typedef of a function type whose declarator includes a *cv-qualifier-seq* shall be used only to declare the function type for a non-static member function, to declare the function type to which a pointer to member refers, or to declare the top-level function type of another function typedef declaration.
>
> *Example:*
>
> ```
> typedef int FIC(int) const;
> FIC f;               // ill-formed: does not declare a member function
> struct S {
>   FIC f;             // OK
> };
> FIC S::*pm = &S::f;  // OK
> ```

Comment: @Nik-Lz True, it's not very common, but it's one of those things where there wasn't a strong reason to specifically forbid it either.  Also, note that since template type parameters follow most of the same rules as typedefs, in `std::function<double(MyClass&, int)>`, the class template `std::function` is essentially using a function typedef.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, `std_fun_1` and `std_fun_2` are identical objects with identical type signatures. They are both `std::function<int(int)>`, and can both hold function pointers or callable objects of type `int(int)`.

`pf` is a pointer to `int(int)`. That is, it serves the same basic purpose as `std::function`, but without the machinery of that class or support for instances of callable objects.

Similarly, `std_fun_3` and `std_fun_4` are identical objects with identical type signatures, and can both hold function pointers or callable objects of type `int(int) const`.

Also similarly, `pfc` is a function pointer of type `int(int) const`, and can hold pointers to functions of that type, but not instances of callable objects.

But `f` and `fc` are **function declarations.**

The line:

```
Signature fc;
```

Is identically equivalent to:

```
int fc(int) const;
```

Which is a declaration for a function named `fc` of type `int(int) const`.

There's nothing strange going on here. You've simply happened upon syntax you probably already understand, from a perspective you're not accustomed to.