# c++ remove noexcept from decltype returned type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17, decltype

```
#include <functional>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


std::function<decltype(::bind)> mockbind = ::bind;

int main()
{
}
```

The code above works on most of the platforms I compile on. But on ubuntu 14.04 using g++-7 I get an error:

```
X.cpp:7:65: error: variable ‘std::function<int(int, const sockaddr*, unsigned int) noexcept> mockbind’ has initializer but incomplete type
 std::function<int(int, const sockaddr*, unsigned int) noexcept> mockbind = ::bind;
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~
```

Now if I manually go and change the type of `mockbind`

```
std::function<int(int, const sockaddr*, unsigned int) noexcept> mockbind = ::bind;
```

As expected I get the same error:
Now if I remove the `noexcept`

```
std::function<int(int, const sockaddr*, unsigned int)> mockbind = ::bind;
```

It compiles as expected.

So the question is can I apply some template code to remove the `noexcept` from the type returned by `decltype` and make it work as expected.

Comment: Doesn't `auto mockbind = ::bind` do what you want?

Comment: @whoan: No because it does not create a `std::function<>` type object. Without which it would be hard to bind funcotors to `mockbind`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple class specialization trick should work:

```
template <typename T> struct remove_noexcept
{
    using type = T;
};
template <typename R, typename ...P> struct remove_noexcept<R(P...) noexcept>
{
    using type = R(P...);
};
template <typename T> using remove_noexcept_t = typename remove_noexcept<T>::type;

// ...

std::function<remove_noexcept_t<decltype(::bind)>> mockbind = ::bind;
```

You could somewhat easily extend it to remove `noexcept` from [member] function pointers, that's left as an excercise to the reader.

Also you could comment out `using type = T;` if you wish to get a compile-time error if there is no `noexcept` instead of leaving the type unchanged.

Comment: I assume this also works adding specialisations for member functions as well

Comment: @SirGuy Yes, it should. I decided to not bother for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Looks. Good. I'll test it tonight when I get home

Comment: @LokiAstari You're welcome, and you just gave me silver [tag:c++] badge. :P

Answer (score 3):

While HolyBlackCat's answer covers the majority of actual use cases, it would fail to cover many possible cases, including a [qualified function type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446559/1136311) (e.g., `int(int) const noexcept`), a variadic templated variadic function (e.g., `template<typename... Ts> void foo(Ts..., ...) noexcept`), and pointer to member functions (which don't operate under normal *pointer* rules at all, e.g., `int(foo::*)(int) noexcept`).

Implementing a `remove_noexcept` trait that covers all of these edge cases is no small undertaking, but here's my take on it. I implemented `remove_noexcept_t` in terms of `make_noexcept_t<T, bool>`, whose second parameter allows you to toggle the resultant `noexcept` state (`noexcept(true)` or `noexcept(false)`, as you'd expect).

Notably, this *does* work with pointer to member functions, but does **not** work with function pointers. This is by design (primarily following the logic of `std::is_pointer`), though you could fairly easily set up a `using` declaration like `add_pointer_t<make_noexcept_t<remove_pointer_t<decay_t<T>>>>`.

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GUqJFwMnczKEKlzX) (*UPDATED* 13 Oct 2022 - Added explicit licensing)

**EDIT:** The below implementation was not tested for accuracy with MSVC++ 2019 (v142) before I posted this. While it does work with GCC and Clang, this implementation does **NOT** work with MSVC++ 2019 (v142). The live demo link has been updated to a *much longer* implementation (twice as many specializations), which is too long to post to StackOverflow. That implementation has been tested with GCC, Clang, and MSVC++ 2019 (v142).

```
template<typename T, bool noexcept_state = true>
struct make_noexcept { using type = T; };

template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile & noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile && noexcept, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };

// MSVC++ 2019 (v142) doesn't allow `noexcept(x)` with a template parameter `x` in the template specialization list.
// (e.g., `struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) noexcept(noexcept_state)>` gives - C2057: expected constant expression)
// GCC 7.1.0 and Clang 5.0.0 (and later versions) were tested and do allow this, so MSVC++ is probably wrong.
// $ g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -pedantic
// $ clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -pedantic

template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...), noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...), noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...)&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...)&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args...) const volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(Args..., ...) const volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(Args..., ...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...), noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...), noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...)&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...)&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile &, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile & noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };
template<bool noexcept_state, typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct make_noexcept<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile &&, noexcept_state> { using type = R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile && noexcept(noexcept_state); };

template<typename T, bool noexcept_state = true>
using make_noexcept_t = typename make_noexcept<T, noexcept_state>::type;

template<typename T>
using remove_noexcept_t = make_noexcept_t<T, false>;
```

Comment: Additionally, this could be used as a basis for an `is_noexcept` trait by checking `is_same_v<T, make_no_except_t<T>>`.

Comment: I tested compilation of this with MSVC++ 2019 (v142), but all of the type check tests were done on Wandbox (GCC and Clang). MSVC++ completely discards `noexcept(noexcept_state)` in every case.

Comment: Thanks for undertaking that tedious task ... *saved me a lot of work*

Comment: It was brought to my attention that SO contributions are implicitly licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0. I updated the live demo link to explicitly include the WTFPL. Attribution is appreciated, but not required.

Comment: Agreed, it is rather an uncommon situation for the use of Stackoverflow, insofar you are publishing complete code here (which is very much appreciated)