# how to deduce parameters of the std::function template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std-function

Regarding the definition of the std::function,

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>;
```

And the instantiation of the template is like this:

```
std::function<int(Foo const&)> f_num = &Foo::num_;
```

I'm confusing that how the parameter can be used like this: int(Foo const&). int and Foo const& are both types.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any deduction going on in your instantiation.

Comment: `R` and `Args` are also types, so no problem. The fact that the template uses `class` and not `typename` [doesn't matter at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function signature-like expressions as C++ template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642079/function-signature-like-expressions-as-c-template-arguments)

Comment: oh, yep, thanks @Klaus

Comment: also, this article should be helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446220/c-function-types