# Removing class pointer from member function pointer type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I saw this code snippet in the example on cppreference for std::is_function and I don't understand how it works. Could someone explain to me why U gets deduced as it does in PM_traits?

```cpp
struct A {
  int fun() const&;
};

template<typename>
struct PM_traits {}; 

template<class T, class U>
struct PM_traits<U T::*> {
  using member_type = U;
};

int main() {
  using T = PM_traits<decltype(&A::fun)>::member_type; // T is int() const&
}
```

Comment: I've verified that this is the deduced type with g++. `T` is in fact `int() const&`.

Comment: Well, it seems you are right. But I have a hard time understanding what a `int() const&` can possibly mean outside the context of a member function. `const` and the ref qualifier `&` are meaningless (and forbidden) on a free function.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you can simply it, by making a simple member function, non-const. It would still be a function type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, they are forbidden on free functions, but not on function types in general. Remember that it's legal to declare (not define) a member function using a typedef, for example. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e27c347a58783f3)

Comment: @Angew That's fascinating, thank you for the example.

Comment: Somewhat related, on qualified function types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446220/c-function-types/17446559

Answer (score 11):

`U T::*` is a type such that when we have `U T::* p`, `p` points to a member of class `T`, and that member is of type `U`.

`fun` is a function of type `int () const &`: a `const &`-qualified function taking no parameters and returning `int`, and it's a member of class `A`. Therefore, in the deduction, `T` is deduced to `A` and `U` is deduced to the type of `A::fun`, which is `int () const &`.

---

It may look a bit confusing, because if the type of `&A::fun` was spelled out explicitly, it would have to be written `int (A::*)() const &`. However, in the template's case, the type `int () const &` is "hidden" behind the name `U`, so the pointer to member is then just `U A::*`. It's similar to how type names can be used to simplify the syntax of normal function pointers:

```
int foo(char, double) { return 42; }

using Fun = int (char, double);
Fun *p = &foo;
// instead of:
int (*q)(char, double) = &foo;
```

The same happens in the template, just with `A::*` instead of `*`.

Comment: I can write `int(A::* p)() const & = &A::fun;` but `int () const & A::* p = &A::fun;` gives me an error. Why is there a discrepancy between what happens here and what happens in templates?

Comment: @willtunnels Because that's how C++ syntax works. Notice that you *can* write `using V = int () const &; V A::* p = &A::fun;`. It's the same as writing `const int *p;` vs. `using T = int*; const T p;`.

Comment: That generally seems to work except when ref qualifiers are introduced. I put in your code exactly and g++ spat out `cannot convert 'int (A::*)() const &' to 'int (A::*)() const' in initialization`. Am I missing something obvious? Can someone confirm that that code actually works for them? (Thanks for your help by the way.)

Comment: So, based on some experimentation, it looks like clang handles this correctly (?) but gcc fails.