# T(U) - What does this syntax mean in c++ template

Tags: c++

I read STL and encounter this pattern:

```
template <typename S>
class F;

// specialization
template <typename T, typename U>
class F<T(U)>{};
```

It compiles OK, so what does `T(U)` mean here?

Comment: It means a function taking a single parameter of type `U` and returning a `T`.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/17446220/4117728

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T(U)` is a *type-id* denoting the type "*function with a single parameter of type `U` and return type `T`*".

However, C++ is context-sensitive and this is only parsed as *type-id* because lookup of `U` finds a type (because it names a type template parameter). If lookup of `U` found a non-type, then `T(U)` would be parsed as expression instead, in which case it would be a *functional-style explicit cast* which is equivalent to the C style cast `(T)U`.

And if both `U` and `T` would name non-types, then it would be parsed as a *function call expression*.

Comment: If U and T both are non-type, how come is `function call expression`? can you explain more about this case?

Comment: @shan I am not sure what I should explain. If you write `something(something_else)`, then that's a call to a function (or object) named `something` with argument `something_else`. (But only if both `something` and `something_else` are expressions, i.e. not types.)